# Cannot use comma as decimal separator for input, with angular/typescript/html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, localization

I have an Angular frontend with hundreds of html input fields, which trigger calculation of a result upon typing.

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel.myAttribute" (input)="calculate()">`

My problem is that the input needs to be able to handle decimals, but the calculation breaks (result displays as NaN) when a number using ',' (comma) as decimal separator is typed/used.
I have registerLocaleData() and LOCALE_ID in providers:[] in app.module which I thought would be enough (this was originally for app-wide localized date formatting, but the "senior" devs at the office say this should change number formatting as well - though this is clearly 'in theory' since they don't have any projects where they had to take decimals as input - and in my case it doesn't even change the display of numbers with decimals to use comma as separator).

This *does* however change the default display in the other dev's projects, and they don't understand why it wouldn't at least [do that] in my case. They've looked over my code, and they can't find anything that would interfere with this behavior (though I have yet to see their projects, so, once again, from my perspective, this is highly theoretical).

Am I (and the other dev's at my office) wrong for thinking registerLocalData() and LOCALE_ID should affect numbers as well?

Are there any other ways to apply local number formatting [on a higher level] to "give it" to all components?

Code examples (copy/pasted from my project, but with renamed variables, with most of them omitted (since they're just variants of the same thing) for simplicity, and really just to "prove" that I don't have any "special" or "weird" code that should interfere with any form of localisation):

**App module**

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID  } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeSe from '@angular/common/locales/sv';

registerLocaleData(localeSe, 'sv-se');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent,
    OtherChildComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    httpInterceptorProviders,
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "sv-se" },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**Parent component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';
import { OtherChildComponent } from '../otherChild/otherChild.component';
import { ParentObject } from '../models';
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
})

export class HarvestComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() parentId!: number;
   @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent!: ChildComponent;
   @ViewChild(OtherChildComponent) otherChildComponent!: OtherChildComponent;

   parentObject!: ParentObject

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private parentSvc: ParentService) {
   }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            if (params['internalReference'] != undefined) {
                this.parentId= params['internalReference'];
                console.log("\n HARVEST ID HAS BEEN SET VIA QUERY PARAMS\n");
        }
        if (this.parentId)
            this.getParentObject().then((object) => {
                this.parentObject = object;
            })
    });
```

**Child component**

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() parentObjectId!: number;
    @Input() otherChildObject!: OtherChildObject;
    @Input() editDisabled: boolean = true;
    mySub!: Subscription;
    myObject!: MyObject;

    constructor(private childSvc: ChildService, private toastr: ToastrService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.parentObjectId && this.parentObjectId != 0)
            this.getChildObject(this.parentObjectId ).then((object) => {
                this.myObject= object;
                this.calculateDiff();
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.toastr.error("An error occurred!");
                console.log(error.message);
            });
    }

    calculateDiff() {
        var var1 = this.myObject.oneAttr as number;
        var var2 = this.otherChildObject.anotherAttr as number;
        var diff = ((var1 - var2 ) / var2) * 100;
        this.myObject.diffAttr = diff;
    }
}
```

My index.html does have a lang tag
`<html lang="sv">`
For certain result-fields I use number pipe to control how many decimals to show, which for some reason enables "correct" *display* of the result, with comma as separator.

`<input type="text" [disabled]="editDisabled" [ngModel]="myModel.myAttribute | number : '1.1-1'">`

Though I would prefer not to have to use this type of solution (like a pipe for every ) more than I already have, since I am dealing with over 200 different input fields - but it also doesn't seem to change the actual ability to *input* a comma as separator, so I guess that is a moot detail anyway.

I've looked around for solutions online, and I've found many (potential ones), but none of them work - at least not without writing custom functions/pipes to change the input decimal separator from ',' to '.' which, once again, I would love to *not* have to do, since it would have to be applied (in one way or another) to basically every one of the hundreds of fields.
I've tested with the same results in FireFox, Chrome, and Edge...

Is there any light to be shed on this issue at all?
Appreciate any and all input.
Thank you.

Comment: My understanding is that you try to have the user input a number. 
In the <input> html element I can see that you have configured the type property to be a "text", but you should configure it to be a "number" input element. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)
It helps with parsing the users input and won't let him input non-numbers.
Since the default input type of a "text" input is a string type, you will get a NaN exception like you described. Hope it helps a little. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Facepalming all over the place...! I can't believe I missed such a stupid detail (but I also can't believe the senior dev's did).
That solved it! Now default separator for decimals is a comma (!). Thank you!

Comment: I added the comment as an answer, please mark it as accepted! :)

Comment: ofc! the least I could do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you try to have the user input a number. In the  html element I can see that you have configured the type property to be a "text", but you should configure it to be a "number" input element. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) It helps with parsing the users input and won't let him input non-numbers. Since the default input type of a "text" input is a string type, you will get a NaN exception like you described. Hope it helps a little. Let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalPipe` is already considering your app's `LOCALE_ID`, so you do not need to specify how to format, get rid of [digitsInfo](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#digitsinfo).

But you should not use it in the input. To take `1,23` for input and store it as `1.23`, `ngx-mask` will help you. With it, you use your input as follows:

```html
<input type="text"
       [disabled]="editDisabled"
       [(ngModel)]="myModel.myAttribute"
       decimalMarker=","
       thousandSeparator="."
       mask="separator.2">
<span>{{myModel.myAttribute | number}}</span>
```

There are many options to `mask`. `.2` defines that input will only accept 2 fractional digits.

You can [configure](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/blob/05de8f520b63cd2befcede596841d6f1b95f2824/projects/ngx-mask-lib/src/lib/ngx-mask.config.ts) `ngx-mask` and specify `thousandSeparator`, `decimalMarker` and much more only once. If you really do not want to search and replace those inputs to add mask directive, you can also wrap `ngx-mask` in custom directive you create, and set that [directive's selector](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) in a manner that it will trigger every input you need to mask. For example it might be `input[type=text]`, alleviating the need to add `mask` to 200 inputs. But editing 200 inputs might be easier!

Comment: although [what you write about] requires some more research for me to fully understand, your code-block proved useful in a couple of cases where I have text and numbers spliced together (it's like a "callsign" and a serial number that the client wants displayed as one), where the serial number has a separator, which they want with a comma (but that always came out with a point/period after processing in ts). So thank you for that! +1